# Jenkins - Error when executing always post condition: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'lastSuccessful' found among steps

Tags: jenkins, build-automation, cicd, jenkins-job-dsl

While running a regression FT suite, which worked perfectly earlier through 'Pipeline Script from SCM', I am facing the CI job failure recently as "No such DSL method 'lastSuccessful' found among steps".

Comment: Please share your Pipeline code.

Comment: stage (“Post Build”) {
        // lastSuccessful
        println(“lastSuccessful” + pwd())
                lastSuccessful()
    }

Comment: @DivyaA ycr meant to edit your question with the code and indent it properly so that it is readable.